# How to track admin activities in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've got Rails 6/Grape API app with active admin on board. Right now I want to have activity logs: monitoring history of changes made by admin such as editing or adding user data. The ideal scenario would be to download this logs in to CSV/XML file.

Is there any gem you can recommend which can cover such an action? Honestly I'd like to avoid writing this from scratch.

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ActiveAdmin Audit](https://github.com/holyketzer/activeadmin-audit) and [ActiveAdmin Versioning](https://github.com/yhirano55/active_admin_versioning). You can also [integrate PaperTrail yourself](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Auditing-via-paper_trail-%28change-history%29).